# Hook Length Formula and Triangular Number

Tags: combinatorics

Show that the number of odd hook lengths minus the number of even hook lengths of a partition $\lambda$ is a triangular number.

**My attempt:**
Catalan number is equivalent to the hook-length formula so I tried using it to derive to the triangular number $k(k+1)/2$ but I am not so sure what to do next.
Please show me how to do it, if there's any better way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hint: the hook lengts in a staircase partition (k,k-1,..,2,1) are all odd, and per definition triangular in number.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ has 2 same parts, $\lambda_i=\lambda_{i+1},$ then $h(i,j)=h(i+1,j)+1$. So, difference between odd and even hooks for these 2 rows is 0. Similarly difference is 0, if two column lengths is same. Since for staircase partition difference is a triangular number, the claim is true.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What do the hook lengths look like if you have two rows (or two columns) of equal length? Use this to reduce the problem to the partitions in Wouter's hint.